# How do I add data from raster::extract to a shapefile and make it a 'feature'?

Tags: arcmap, r, shapefile, symbology

In R, I extracted the mean of a raster (`Masking`) using a shapefile (`newcounty`) (broken up into counties). It returned a mean value `temp` for each county, which I added to `newcounty` below.

```
library(raster)
library(sf)

county<-st_read("C:\\Users\\Documents\\Shapefiles/COUNTY.shp")
newcounty<-st_transform (county, crs = st_crs(4326))
#Get the mean of the points for each county
extracted<-raster::extract(Masking,newcounty,method = "simple",mean,na.rm=TRUE)
newcounty$temp<-extracted
testshp<-as_Spatial(newcounty)
shapefile(testshp,"COUNTYSTATS.shp")
```

When I read the shapefile into ArcMap it looked like there were only 2 'features'. My new `temp` column was not showing up as a feature. I would like to be able to change the symbology to show counties that are warmer as 'darker' but when I tried to choose graduated colors, I only had two options (not including my new 'temp'.

[image]

Did I write out the shapefile incorrectly in R? How can I make my new column in the attribute table a feature?

Comment: Careful how you use "feature" here - in spatial data a "feature" is a *row* in the table, ie a geographic "feature" (this is the "Simple Features Standard") but in machine learning contexts its a *column*, which is what I think you are using here.

Comment: You might be getting some problems here because you are mixing and matching `sf` and `sp` classes, and the output from `extract` is a matrix (even though its only got one column) and I can elicit a "Can't convert columns of class: matrix; column names: temp" error when mucking with these things. You don't need to convert to `as_Spatial` and then use `shapefile` to write, you can write `sf` polygons to shapefile with `st_write`.